# Is there a a way to migrate data from Core Data to Online Database?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

My app currently uses core data.  I created a new version of the app that is all cloud based and the database is online.  Therefore this requires user registration/accounts to access the data.  The easiest thing is for me to make it a separate app, but then I lose the user base I already have.

Is there a way for me to transfer data from the iPhone's core data database to the online database? I am using https://www.parse.com/

Comment: Have you ever found a nice solution to this Core Data -> Parse?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look into this github project,

https://github.com/itsniper/FTASync

Comment: Who's had any luck using it to sync to Parse robustly?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. To transfer data from CoreData to Parse, just create a PFObject for each row in your CoreData table, and save them to Parse. You can use saveAll to be faster. Then, you don't need the local copy in CoreData any more, so you can remove it.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. But how do I implement the actual code that runs after the first run after the user updated the app, and copies the data over, then checks if data has been copied, then deletes core data model.